# Gravity Forms Pre Populate Dropdown working but only after I click Update Form

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

Using the example below I can successfully populate a dropdown in the Gravityforms editor with a list of states that are stored in my database table...

```
add_filter("gform_pre_render_3", populate_dropdown1); //5 is the GF Form ID
add_filter("gform_admin_pre_render_3", populate_dropdown1);

function populate_dropdown1($form){
global $wpdb; //Accessing WP Database (non-WP Table) use code below.
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT btc_state_short from btc_state_list");

$choices = array();
$choices[] = array("text" => "Select a State", "value" => ""); //adding a array option with no value, this will make the user select and option.

foreach ($results as $result) {
$choices[] = array("text" => $result->btc_state_short, "value" => $result->btc_state_short);
}

foreach($form["fields"] as &$field){
if($field["id"] == 1){
$field["choices"] = $choices;
}
}

return $form;
}
```

This works great, but ONLY once you have clicked 'Update Form'.  When you just create the dropdown initially it has the standard fields...

```
First Choice
Second Choice
Third Choice
```

Is there a way to pre-populate this as soon as it is dragged in?

Answer (score 0):

In Gravity Forms that issue was resolved in the recent version of the form fields. Once you select DropDown and it is on your field to be generated there is now a complete common list of dropdowns. There is a button titled "Bulk Add / Predefined Choices) right below the Common generated fields (i.e. First Choice Second Choice Third Choice)....

Just click that button and select the field you wish to auto populate and it will fill.

Hope that helps.

EP System Technologies Tech

using GravityForms Version 1.8.17 | By rocketgenius |